# System dark mode is overriding my System Alert window

Tags: android, android-layout

I have implemented a System Alert Window, And that window has its own UI. But when dark mode is enabled, then that layout is overriding the colours I have given.

```
private fun showAlert(context: Context,message:String){
    val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder( ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.RigTheme))
    val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val dialogView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_rig_alert, null)

    

    dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvMessage).text = message

    builder.setView(dialogView)
    val alert: AlertDialog = builder.create()

    val window = alert.window ?: return
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    val layoutFlag: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
    } else {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
    }
    window.setType(layoutFlag)
    alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

    alert.show()
    val lp: WindowManager.LayoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams()

    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
    lp.copyFrom(window.attributes)
    //This makes the dialog take up the full width
    //This makes the dialog take up the full width
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    window.attributes = lp
    
    // Click stuff

}
```

And the style

```
    <style name="RigTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
         <item name="colorAccent">@color/light_red</item>
         <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
         <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/txt_grey</item>
         <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
         <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
```

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardElevation="10dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/curve_bg"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_close"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/close"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/warning"
        android:textColor="@color/light_red"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_close" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_grey"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_rect_un_selected"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_grey"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnDoit"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvMessage" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDoit"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_rect_selected"
        android:text="@string/do_it_now"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnCancel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvMessage" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I have 2 issues with this code.

### Issue 1

The dark mode is overriding the colour combination

original UI
[image: required Ui]

when dark mode is enabled
[image: dark mode overriding]

### Issue 2

I need to align the widgets in the centre. I have given WRAP_CONTENT, but the dialog is taking most of the screen width. and of course, the widgets are aligned left.

Answer (score 0):

check this tip from the docs:

Tip: If you want a custom dialog, you can instead display an Activity as a dialog instead of using the Dialog APIs. Simply create an activity and set its theme to Theme.Holo.Dialog in the  manifest element:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
```

That's it. The activity now displays in a dialog window instead of fullscreen.

I haven't tried it, but i think that inside the activity it will be easier to place your views without the alignment issues, also you can specify a Light theme with Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.